# cannot setup searchbar swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I need to setup a tableview with sections of a set of locations.
I managed to do all of it but now I'm stuck with the searchbar that helps the user to find certain locations if they know the name.

Here is my code:

```
class PlacesList: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    struct LocationsStruct {
        let name: String
        let lat: CLLocationDegrees
        let long: CLLocationDegrees
        let image: UIImage
        let description: String
    }        
    let cellId = "cellId"
    let twoDiemArray = [
        [LocationsStruct(name: "Jolie Golf ", lat: 27.949315, long: 34.363702, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotelIcon"), description: "sessions are held here"),
         LocationsStruct(name: "Club Reef Hotel", lat: 27.887805, long: 34.324911, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotelIcon"), description: "hello"),
         LocationsStruct(name: "Dreams Beach Resort", lat: 27.875648, long: 34.317508, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotelIcon"), description: "hello"),
         LocationsStruct(name: "Ras Mohamed Nature Reserve", lat: 27.747882, long: 34.235658, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotelIcon"), description: "hello")
    ],            
        [LocationsStruct(name: "Jolie Restaurant ", lat: 27.949315, long: 34.363702, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotelIcon"), description: "you can eat here"),
         LocationsStruct(name: "Club ", lat: 27.887805, long: 34.324911, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotelIcon"), description: "you can dance here"),
         LocationsStruct(name: " Beach", lat: 27.875648, long: 34.317508, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotelIcon"), description: "you can swim here")]
    ]

    var filteredData = [
    [LocationsStruct]
    ]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        filteredData = twoDiemArray
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }
```

And this is the function where I'm stuck. The one that accepts text in search bar and filters data based on that text:

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = twoDiemArray.filter({( location : LocationsStruct) -> Bool in
            return location.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })

        if searchText == "" {
            filteredData = twoDiemArray
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I get the error:

> Value of type '[PlacesList.LocationsStruct]' has no member 'name'

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a nested array so location is not an object it's an array  , so you can try

```
filteredData = twoDiemArray.filter { (locations) -> Bool in

       return locations.filter { (location) -> Bool in
            return location.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
     }.count != 0

}
```

Comment: that gives an error "Cannot convert value of type '[PlacesList.LocationsStruct]' to closure result type 'Bool'"

Comment: i cannot use single dimension array as i need sections in my tableview, thats why im using the two dimensions one

Comment: didn't need to, it was my previous solution already but i changed it as i need the 2 dimension array, thanks anyway